# Clearcase Woes with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, version-control

I am using clearcase as my versioning system. I have problems with the mapped views. My project contains few components which are required to be registered using admin privliges.

On booting up, the the drives are mounted using non-elevated explorer and these are drives are unable to access if Visual Studio starts in elevated mode.

I found following workaround for this situation

1. use a batch file to build the projects and before starting the batch file map the view to a temporary drive in the elevated command prompt using net use command.
2. Alway start Explorer in elevated mode. I don't know how we do this and don't know if some security constraints are there.

Is there any other way to sort out these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that "mapped views" are:

- [simple `subst`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK21629) (a Windows command, nothing to do with ClearCase)
- still accessible, in case of dynamic views, with "`m:\myDynView\...`"

So if you can re-do those `subst` with the right privilege, that should be enough.